# How to center text-boxes and draw a rule from each box

Tags: tcolorbox, tikz-styles, boxes, rules

I know my headline sounds highly confusing so let me provide you my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{frameGray}{enhanced, colframe=black,colback=gray!3.5, boxrule=0.2pt,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,frame hidden, after skip = 12pt}

\newcommand{\boxGray}[1]{\tikz[baseline=(X.base)]\node [draw=gray!25,fill=gray!0,ultra thin,rectangle,inner sep=4pt,align=left] (X) {#1};}

\definecolor{bturq}{rgb}{0.0, 0.87, 0.87}

\newcommand{\raisedrule}[2][0em]{\leaders\hbox{\rule[#1]{1pt}{#2}}\hfill}

\newcommand{\hs}{\hspace{-6pt}}



\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{frameGray}

\hs\boxGray{name, name:} \textcolor{bturq!60}{\raisedrule[3pt]{0.5pt}} \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\boxGray{name, name}} 

\vspace{10pt}

\hs\boxGray{place:} \textcolor{bturq!60}{\raisedrule[3pt]{0.5pt}} \parbox{0.4\textwidth}{\boxGray{place \\  place}}

\end{frameGray}

\end{document}
```

This will create some text-boxes with a rule that is horizontally connected to other text-boxes.

**What I want** is the text-boxes on the left to be centered on top each other, but still with a rule coming out right where the text-boxes end (as is it is right now, just that the boxes are not centered but left aligned). Seems tricky.

**Sketch**:

I got:

```
name, name ------------------- name, name

                               place 
place ------------------------ 
                               place
```

I want:

```
name, name ------------------- name, name

                               place 
  place ---------------------- 
                               place
```

So that the text on the left is centered but the rules are still coming out from it.

Comment: hm, a sketch what you after will help us a lot to prepare an answer ...

Comment: I edited a sketch. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for editing of question!

[image]

Is this what you after?

Above solution use of the `tikzmark` library, packages `tabularx` and `makecell`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}

\newtcolorbox{frameGray}{
    enhanced, 
    frame hidden,
    colback=gray!3.5, 
    arc=0pt,   
    after skip = 12pt}


\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\begin{frameGray}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{c X l}
\tikzmarknode{a}{name, name:}
    &   &   \tikzmarknode{b}{name, name}   \\[10pt] 
\tikzmarknode{c}{place:}
    &   &   \tikzmarknode{d}{\makecell[l]{place\\ place}} 
    \end{tabularx}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,
                        arr/.style = {color=cyan, semithick, shorten <=4pt, shorten >=4pt}
                        ]
\draw[arr]   (a) -- (b);
\draw[arr]   (c) -- (d);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frameGray}

\end{document}
```

For showed result you need to compile MWE three times.

Comment: Awesome, looks amazing!